# Java: Unable to get Median calculated with code

Tags: java, arrays, median

I have two files that I am using for my Array median code.  The first file( ArrayMedian.java) is used to collect and then calculate the median, the second file is the tester file ( ArrayMedianTest.java)

I was supplied with some source code and needed to modify it accept a set range for each number in the dataset.  I got that part done and the random range displays, but now when I get to he array it no longer calculates, I really can't put my finger on what is going wrong.

Another thing I am trying to do is in the ArrayMedian, is put a while loop in there to make it terminate if a '0' is input for the dataset, but it does not seem to want to work in that file, could it be due to no main in the file?

```
package bonus2.u06.exercise.ex3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayMedian {

    private int[] arr;  // just declare array
    Scanner keyboard;   // shared field 

    // initialize keyboard and array
    public void init() {
        keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );    
        System.out.print("Enter the dataset size: ");

        int size = keyboard.nextInt(); // must be odd number
        arr = new int[ size ];   // instantiate 
    }

    // Randomize the array
    public void getRange() {        
        //System.out.println("\nYou entered: ");
        System.out.print("Enter a Range: ");
        int range = keyboard.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("array: \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            int myRnd = (int)( range * Math.random() );

            System.out.print(" " + myRnd + " ");
        }
    }

    // find the median of array
    public int calcMedian() {
        int half_length = arr.length/2;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count == half_length) {
                 //<=========  terminate this method
                return arr[i];
            }

        }

        return 0;   
    }

}
```

ArrayMedianTest:

```
package bonus2.u06.exercise.ex3;

public class ArrayMedianTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // instantiate 
        ArrayMedian obj = new ArrayMedian();
        // execute all methods 
        obj.init();
        obj.getRange();

        int median = obj.calcMedian();
        System.out.println("\nmedian : " + median);

        System.out.println("\n--- done ---");
    }   

}
```

Comment: You're never actually filling `arr` with the randomized data. I think you forgot to include `arr[i] = myRnd`.

Comment: Sweet, I added that bit after my int myRnd and fixed the issue with the median!  Thank you!  Now if I could figure out why I can't use a while loop.

Comment: What do you mean by, you can't use a while loop?

Comment: Any time I try to put a while loops outside of a method, I am being told I have a syntax error, "while", invalid AnnotationName.

Comment: Using Arrays.sort() would be faster and simpler as it is `O(N log N)`

Comment: Since you are adding non-unique values there might not be a value which is exactly the 50% or median.  It could be that your median appears many times. e.g. the count might be 48 out of 100 for one value and 55 out of 100 for the next value.

Comment: Since ArrayMedian doesn't have a main, I believe that is the reason I can't put a while loop outside of method.  I tried putting a while loop just on 'public void init' but of course it would just loop that one part and never go to 'public void getRange'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out, your algorithm works perfectly fine, except in the `getRange()` method, you forgot to set the values of the array, so the array is an array of zeros. Here is how it should look:

```
public void getRange() {        
    //System.out.println("\nYou entered: ");
    System.out.print("Enter a Range: ");
    int range = keyboard.nextInt(); 

    System.out.print("array: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        int myRnd = (int)( range * Math.random() );

        System.out.print(" " + myRnd + " ");
        arr[i] = myRnd; // <-- You missed this line right here!
    }
}
```

Also, as a recomendation, if you want to put code in stackoverflow, it has to have a spacing of four at the begining of the line plus any indenting you might use. Good luck programming!